# Logging module: how to save appending file while executing script in Python?

Tags: python, logging, module, append

I wrote a script that keeps running 24/7 and I can only get the content of the logger.log file if I interupt its execution. It needs to be in append mode, so I can have a backtrack of the script. Is there any way to access the Logger file while the script is running and it is still kept updating? This is the standard configuration that I use for that.

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='arquivos/logger.log', level=logging.INFO, filemode='a', 
                format='%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(levelname)s %(module)s - %(funcName)s: %(message)s',
                datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Comment: What do you mean accessing the log file? I just tried out your config and put "logger.info("foo") into an infinite loop. I could access the file, while the program was running and it was appened constantly. Only thing is that I had to create the file before running the code.

Comment: @BalázsSipos I don't know what's happening them. I have to stop the program to get the updated file. Otherwise it will be on the last version before I restarted the program.

Comment: Okay. I just found out what is maybe happening. I'm running this project inside a Google Driver folder on my home server and it is not updating, but when I moved it to my server desktop it started appending normally. Honestly, this is probably a huge headache to fix it. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Happy to hear, sadly I don't have an idea how to fix that... good luck!